# Quickly Groupby Large DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame of 100M rows and 8 columns. I'm trying to groupby my DataFrame by 5 string columns and perform the following calculations as fast as possible.

```
    df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E'])['F'].transform('median')
    df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E']).agg({'F':'count', 'G':['mean','median','std'], 'H':['mean','std']})
```

I'm assuming doing it using numpy arrays would be the fastest, but I don't even know where to begin because it takes a couple of minutes just to convert a column to a numpy array.

Comment: I suggest use [dask](https://dask.org/) here.

Comment: how about using `pandas`' big brother `dask`? You can do `import dask.dataframe as dd` and then `df = dd.read_csv(file)`. Then run all the code above. It also can read `sql` or however you are reading in the data.